# How to have a question stop being asked once a variable goes beyond a limit

Tags: python

I'm working on a text adventure game and am unsure how to get a question to stop being asked once the **playerHealth** variable is less than or equal to 0. Anyway, heres the code:

```
from random import *


hydraSerpent = 100

playerHealth = 100
attackDamage = randint(0,100)



while hydraSerpent != 0:
    try:
        attack = input("Would you like to do a heavy attack? [heavy] ")
    except ValueError:
        clear()


    if attack == "heavy" and attackDamage >= 1:
        playerHealth = playerHealth - 65
        print("""The hydra then attacks you for 65 health
        you are on {} health""".format(playerHealth))



if playerHealth >= 0:
    print("You are dead")
```

Comment: You aren't decrementing the health of the `hydraSerpent` anywhere...

Comment: If this line ```attackDamage = randint(0,100)``` evaluated to ```0```, your ```while``` statement will keep looping infinitely if your memory permits! Otherwise, just put last ```if statement``` into ```while``` block, and changed its header to ```if player health <= 0:``` and its block as ```print('You are dead'); break```.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the player health check to the while loop.

```
from random import *


hydraSerpent = 100

playerHealth = 100
attackDamage = randint(0,100)



    while hydraSerpent != 0 and playerHealth > 0:
        try:
            attack = input("Would you like to do a heavy attack? [heavy] ")
        except ValueError:
            clear()
    
    
        if attack == "heavy" and attackDamage >= 1:
            playerHealth = playerHealth - 65
            print("""The hydra then attacks you for 65 health
            you are on {} health""".format(playerHealth))
    
    
    
    if playerHealth >= 0:
        print("You are dead")
```

Comment: Thankyou it worked, just as i posted the question I added that too and it worked but thankyou anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use `break`!

```
while hydraSerpent != 0:
    # ...
    if attack == "heavy" and attackDamage >= 1:
        playerHealth = playerHealth - 65
        if playerHealth <= 0:  # <-- do this
            break
        print("""The hydra then attacks you for 65 health
        you are on {} health""".format(playerHealth))

if playerHealth >= 0:
    print("You are dead")
```